# Email invoice (MVC web page) from asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, printing, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a MVC website that process transactions, and then renders a page with the transaction information as an invoice.

And i have an option to print the page as the receipt.

The invoice is nicely styled with bootstrap and more custom styles,

I was asked to make an option to email the invoice to the email on the transaction

now my question is, if there is a way to render the page on the server as a PDF, and email it without returning the page to the client,

Also if its possible, i will need to make the PDF with the print CSS styles applied, because there is a lot of stuff that is hidden on the page at print.

Comment: Those are two questions. Try to search.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to render an ASP.NET MVC View in PDF format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324597/how-to-render-an-asp-net-mvc-view-in-pdf-format)

Comment: I have been in PDF from HTML creation problems several times, seen all nuget packages that render HTML to PDF and they all suck. What i did after all is generated word file and then virtually scanned it to pdf. Not ideal as you baically get pictures of pages, and size may or may not be an issue, but it looks exactly the same as in word, tables, decorations, everything. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I use Rotativa which convert razor view to pdf and keeps the css styles and layouts.

It works very well for me.

https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa

The nuget link is as below. Looks like a lot people are using it.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rotativa